# Configure SMTP server on windows server 2008 to send emails from web application

Tags: asp.net, email, configuration, smtp

i have this web application written in C# under ASP.NET 4.0 that runs on a Windows 2008 server. I want to send emails to users from username@mydomain.com but i am unable to. I'm using the following method (**which worked using smtp.gmail.com**) and using System.Net.Mail;

```
        string from = "user@mydomain.com";
        string password = "12345";

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(to);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mail.Subject = title;
        mail.Body = message;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "stmp ip here";
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, password);
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;

        smtp.Send(mail);
```

I have installed and configure SMTP server using basic authentication and outbound security -> basic authentication (using user@mydomain.com and 12345 as password). In IIS7 on my website i clicked on SMTP E-mail and entered the ip of my SMTP server together with the credentials from above.

Before doing all this config, i run into problems like the emails being stuck in the queue folder, server does not support ssl connections and others. Now, the only error i receive when sending email is logged from my application: **The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.3 Client was not authenticated** and the email is not arriving at destination. *The Queue folder is empty and i don't have any errors from the SMTP server log!*

I did alot of research on google about it but i can't fix it. Telnet is working as it should, port 25 is not blocked and disabling windows firewall is not helping either. I'm really stuck. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the server may require you to set 'EnableSsl' to 'true'. So, you could either try to disable this on your server or simply set 'EnableSSl = true' in your client. You will probably then need to change the port to 587 or (sometimes) 465.

Comment: when i set EnableSSL = true i get an error like "server does not support ssl connections". Why do you suggest changing the port?

Comment: Generally secure SMTP connections are not conducted over port 25. Usually they are over port 587 (or sometimes port 465).